# Can I create a module level function object dynamically from string

Tags: python

For example,

I want to create a function object from .

```
mystr = \
"""
def foo(a=1): 
    print a
    pass
"""
```

However, using compile(mystr) will only give me a code object. I want to have module level function object just like the string is part of the source code.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec mystr`

will execute the code you have given.

Answer (score 2):

Yes use [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=exec%20statement#the-exec-statement):

```
>>> mystr = \
"""
def foo(a=1): 
    print a
    pass
"""
>>> exec mystr
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x0274F0F0>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `compile` here, it supports modes like `exec`,`eval`,`single`:

```
In [1]: mystr = \
"""
def foo(a=1): 
        print a
        pass
"""
   ...: 

In [2]: c=compile(mystr,"",'single')

In [3]: exec c

In [4]: foo
Out[4]: <function __main__.foo>
```

help on `compile`:

```
In [5]: compile?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
String Form:<built-in function compile>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:
compile(source, filename, mode[, flags[, dont_inherit]]) -> code object

Compile the source string (a Python module, statement or expression)
into a code object that can be executed by the exec statement or eval().
The filename will be used for run-time error messages.
The mode must be 'exec' to compile a module, 'single' to compile a
single (interactive) statement, or 'eval' to compile an expression.
The flags argument, if present, controls which future statements influence
the compilation of the code.
The dont_inherit argument, if non-zero, stops the compilation inheriting
the effects of any future statements in effect in the code calling
compile; if absent or zero these statements do influence the compilation,
in addition to any features explicitly specified.
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `compile` and then `exec` if `exec` alone does the job?